# Exception notifier only in Production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I use **Exception Notifier** for handling errors in my app and in `/config/initializers/exception_notification.rb` I have followings:

```
MyAPP::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email_prefix => "[ERROR] ",
  :sender_address => '"Notifier" <notifier@yourdomain.com>',
  :exception_recipients => ['account@gmail.com']
```

But the notification email is sent also in development mode, how can I allow sending email only in production mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the ExceptionNotifier separately for each environment. [See also the documentation](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification).

> As of Rails 3 ExceptionNotification is used as a rack middleware, so
>   you can configure its options on your config.ru file, or in the
>   environment you want it to run. In most cases you would want
>   ExceptionNotification to run on production.

So you just configure it in your `config/environments/production.rb` with e.g.

```
Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email_prefix => "[Whatever] ",
  :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@example.com>},
  :exception_recipients => %w{exceptions@example.com}
```

There is also [a nice blog entry handling this topic](http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/basic-exception-notification-in-rails-3/).